# JQuery Carousel atrapalhando o display: inline-block

Tags: jquery, css, css3

A página é essa:

http://www.magicforbaby.com.br/loja/produto.php?p=1

O código é esse:

```
echo "<div class='fotosProduto'>";
require_once "_required/carousel.php";
echo "</div>";


echo '    
  <div class="detalhesProduto">
    texto
  </div>';
```

Dentro de

```
require_once "_required/carousel.php";
```

Tem uma validação se existe fotos para o produto.

Caso existam, exibe o carousel, caso contrário exibe um texto dizendo que não tem fotos.

O problema é o seguinte:

Colocou o seguinte estilo

```
  .fotosProduto, .detalhesProduto {
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align:middle;
      width:400px;
      height:300px;
  }

  .fotosProduto {
      text-align:center;
  }
```

Quando não tem fotos para o produto, as duas div's ficam uma ao lado da outra. Mas quando há fotos e o carousel entra em cena, então a div da direita vai para baixo e não estou conseguindo resolver isso!

css do plugin:

```
/** Stage container **/

.connected-carousels .stage {
    width: 620px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.connected-carousels .photo-credits {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    opacity: .66;
}

.connected-carousels .photo-credits a {
    color: #fff;
}

/** Navigation container **/

.connected-carousels .navigation {
    width: 260px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

/** Shared carousel styles **/

.connected-carousels .carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.connected-carousels .carousel ul {
    width: 20000em;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.connected-carousels .carousel li {
    float: left;
}

/** Stage carousel specific styles **/

.connected-carousels .carousel-stage {
    height: 400px;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}

/** Navigation carousel specific styles **/

.connected-carousels .carousel-navigation {
    height: 60px;
    width: 240px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}

.connected-carousels .carousel-navigation li {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.connected-carousels .carousel-navigation li img {
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.connected-carousels .carousel-navigation li.active img {
    border-color: #ccc;
}

/** Stage carousel controls **/

.connected-carousels .prev-stage,
.connected-carousels .next-stage {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 410px;
    color: #fff;
}

.connected-carousels .prev-stage {
    left: 0;
}

.connected-carousels .next-stage {
    right: 0;
}

.connected-carousels .prev-stage.inactive,
.connected-carousels .next-stage.inactive {
    display: none;
}

.connected-carousels .prev-stage span,
.connected-carousels .next-stage span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
    font: 24px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
       -moz-border-radius: 30px;
            border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}

.connected-carousels .prev-stage span {
    left: 20px;
}

.connected-carousels .next-stage span {
    right: 20px;
}

.connected-carousels .prev-stage:hover span,
.connected-carousels .next-stage:hover span {
    display: block;
}

/** Navigation carousel controls **/

.connected-carousels .prev-navigation,
.connected-carousels .next-navigation {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
    font: 16px/29px Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
       -moz-border-radius: 30px;
            border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}

.connected-carousels .prev-navigation {
    left: -15px;
    top: 22px;
    text-indent: 6px;
}

.connected-carousels .next-navigation {
    right: -15px;
    top: 22px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.connected-carousels .prev-navigation.inactive,
.connected-carousels .next-navigation.inactive {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Não sei como exatamente está a disposição de seu layout, mas pode tentar um "float:none", ou um "clear" na div=fotosProdutos....

Comment: Nenhuma das duas opções deu funcionou!

Comment: Note também que além do bloco que teoricamente deveria estar ao lado direito das fotos (carolsel), ale´m de ir para baixo, foi para o lado esquerdo (abaixo do menu)!

Comment: Fiquei meio perdido, mas se entendi deve funcionar. Tente o seguinte: no div que deve ficar à esquerda adiciona float: left; e complementa o display: inline-block !important;

Comment: ainda não deu!
Será que devo trocar de plugin? Adicionei o css do plugin à pergunta!

Comment: Bom, troquei o plugin: não deve ter ficado uma das 7 maravilhas do mundo (como o meu Vascão, rsrs), mas resolveu meu problema. Vê se ficou fazendo favor?